# Tab focus to radio button in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, accessibility

Just after some help with tab focusing to a radio button, which is in some dynamically created JavaScript. I didn't build the script but I am trying to re-engineer it for my purposes and make it more WCAG2.0 compliant.

If you tab you can see I have added a red dotted border to obviously highlight the selected item. I can't seem to figure out how to bring the focus to the radio buttons in the dynamic script (the quiz), tried tab-index, adding labels, values and id's with no success.

Something needs to be tweaked in 'quiz.js' but my JavaScript skills aren't good enough to figure it out.

quiz.js is large so I haven't posted, all is in JSFiddle.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/C0111N5/YkRRw/

Any help would be helpful!

```
<p></p>
```

Comment: Please don't try to get around StackOverflow rules by posting dummy code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to focus on those elements, the way radio buttons work with the keyboard is you tab to the set (as one tab stop) and use arrow keys to select one.

Just as a test, try this in the CSS instead of your current selectors:

```
*:focus {outline: 2px red dashed !important;}
```

The difference in how they work is due to the HTML, the input at the top (where the CSS applies) is:

```
<input type="radio" name="radio" id="yes" value="yes">
<label for="yes">Yes</label>
```

The input generated from the quiz.js is:

```
<label><input type="radio" name="answer" data-correct="false">True</label>
```

As the label is wrapping the input your selector `input[type=radio]:focus + label` won't work there.

If you search for `<label>` in quiz.js you can adjust that to work the same as your first example, so the label doesn't wrap the input:

```
var $answer = 
"<p><input type='"+settings.currentQuestion.inputTypeHTML+"'
name='answer' data-correct='"+this.correct+"'><label>"
+this.answer+"</label></p>"
```

I would also suggest using `outline` instead of `border`, as outline doesn't affect the layout as you tab through, and means you don't get the user-agent outline applying as well as your border.